# Pattern for class attribute that can only be altered by others

Tags: class, inheritance, design-patterns, visibility, class-visibility

So let's say I have a Door class and a Lock class. Instances of the Door class have a `lock` property that is an instance of the Lock class.

I want the door to "own" it's instance of the Lock but I don't want the door to be able to alter its own lock. For example I DONT want this to be possible:

```
class FancyDoor extends Door {
    function unlockMyself() {
        $this->lock->locked = false;
    }
}
```

But I DO want a door's lock to be accessible to other classes. For example, I need a DoorMan class to be able to lock and unlock doors. So it's not as simple as just making all of the Lock properties private.

Is there a pattern for doing this? I'm primarily working in PHP but an answer does need to be language-specific. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your concern is that, once FancyDoor has been coded *without* an `unlockMyself` method, some developer in future can inadvertently add it and screw the contract.

Avoiding this would be very difficult if the `lock` is owned by `Door`, given the very nature of classes. I can think of the following:

- `Door` doesn't have a `lock` instance.
- `Lock` is modeled as a separate class. You can use State Pattern for it, because:

  - You might want to add more states, apart from `lock` and `unlock`, in future.
  - The same class can be reused to work with, say, `Window`s in future. It needn't be tied with `Door`s.
- A `DoorManager` or something that is composed of these two objects. This class exposes methods for locking/unlocking the `Door` instance that it has.

Essentially, `DoorManager` is responsible for one `Door`, and the `Lock` associated with it.

Comment: Right. This is what I'm doing now, but it's a big clunky because I always have to pass the Door and the Lock together and the manager has to keep track of whose is whose.

Comment: Put both of them in one class and pass object of that class around, rather than passing both of them separately.